# Downgrade android app which is not on playstore

Tags: android, installation

My android app is of version 3 now. I reverted it to version code 2. It throws error saying "Downgrade detected: Update version code 2 is older than current 3" in logs. Whereas upgrade from 2 to 3 is successful.

On screen it is shown as "Error parsing the package" and installation failed.

Can I downgrade the app?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No you can not upload on play store or install in device with downgrade version code.

Comment: why you downgrade version code.it not allowed by play store to update??

Comment: The Version is just a number but you can rollback the previous code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have installed app with greater version number then the one you are currently trying to install you will get an error. That being said, since you did not publish the app you can just uninstall the app from your phone and install the downgraded version on it.

Edit:
If you already published the app outside of playstore(same rule applies for playstore) you should only publish apps with greater version number.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate version 3.0, Activate Version 2.0.

I don't know if that will downgrade anyone who has already upgraded to 3.0, but it will stop anyone who hasn't upgraded from downloading 2.0.

If you want to be sure that everyone goes back to the code from version 2.0, you may need to re-distribute 2.0 as 4.0 which will guarantee people on 3.0 can "upgrade" to the old code base.